# 'Float object is not callable' when dividing class function by a number

Tags: python

I have a class `Portfolio` with a method `portfolio_risk(self, year)`.If I try and divide it by a number I get the error

> Float object is not callable

From my understanding the error is arising due to the parenthesis from the `portfolio_risk` method but I need to call the method to do the calculation. Is there a different way I could write this code to avoid the error?

```
if Portfolio.portfolio_risk(1)/5 < 7:
    print('meets criteria')
```

EDIT: I have added some more information below:

My class is as follows:

```
class Portfolio(import_data):

    def __init__(self, number_yrs):

        self.debt = [0 for i in range(number_yrs)]

        # the import_csv function just pulls a data table from excel and creates a list
        # the list is 2D and creates a property called self.sub_portfolio in this class
        # all the values imported from the csv file are of type float 
        self.import_csv('sub_portfolio') 
        self.debt[0] = self.debt_portfolio

    def portfolio_risk(self, year):

        # this sums up the risk column of a portfolio to give total risk for a year

        self.portfolio_risk = sum(a[0] for a in self.debt[year])
        return(self.portfolio_risk)
```

If I create an instance of this class:

```
new_portfolio = Portfolio(5)
```

My Portfolio class is contained in a file portfolio_class.py and the following line works correctly within this file when I test it:

```
print(new_portfolio.portfolio_risk(0))
```

In another file, analysis.py, I have the following code:

```
 nyears = 10
 real_portfolio = Portfolio(nyears)
 for i in range(nyears):

    if i > 0:

        # first use last prior year portfolio
        the_debt_portfolio.debt[i] = the_debt_portfolio.debt[i-1]


    if real_portfolio.portfolio_risk(i)/ 5 < 7:

        print('this is within the risk band')
```

I now seem to be getting the error:

```
  line 29, in portfolio_risk
  self.portfolio_risk = sum(a[0] for a in self.portfolio_risk[year])
  TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

And not the Float object is not callable error

Comment: It looks like `Portfolio.portfolio_risk` is a `float`, not a method.  Try printing it in the line before the `if`.

Comment: Is portfolio_risk a class method?

Comment: Apparently portfolio_risk is not a method but a float.  Please show your class so we can have a closer look at it.

Comment: Can you post your code for your `Portfolio` class and `portfolio_risk` method? Also please post the full error/stacktrace you get.

Comment: Originally I was trying to condense a long piece of code, but I have added the full error and code above now

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

1. `If` should be `if` (lowercase `i`);
2. You need an instance of `Portfolio` in order to be able to call the (non-static) method.

That said, it's not entirely clear how you'd get that exact exception. One possibility is that somewhere you rebind `portfolio_risk` to a `float`. Even then, the capitalized `If` would produce a syntax error.

I think the best way forward is for you to fix the two problems mentioned above and, if that doesn't help, post more code.

Answer (score 3):

If the method is defined like this

```
class Portfolio(object):
    def portfolio_risk(self, year):
        return 1
```

then you must have an instance of `Portfolio`:

```
p = Portfolio()
if p.portfolio_risk(1) / 5 < 7:
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
portfolio = Portfolio() # you may need to pass some parameters

if portfolio.portfolio_risk(1) / 5 < 7:
    print('meets criteria')
```

Of course, if `portfolio_risk` is a field and not a method you'll still get that error.